# How to Turn the Image when i click imagebutton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-imageview

Can anyone tell me, I have developed Android "Pair Game". So i need When i click on the imagebutton, It turns the image and display a animal or birds image. Please advice me, How can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything before?

Comment: s but i didn't get exact result.

Comment: Exactly what do you want? The post may works. But, you've to customize that with your needs.

Comment: ya. Exactly I want this only..thanks SpK.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer If that satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the animation effect for this -

```
package com.example.flip3d;

import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class Flip3dAnimation  extends Animation {
private final float mFromDegrees;
private final float mToDegrees;
private final float mCenterX;
private final float mCenterY;
private Camera mCamera;

public Flip3dAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees,
   float centerX, float centerY) {
mFromDegrees = fromDegrees;
mToDegrees = toDegrees;
mCenterX = centerX;
mCenterY = centerY;
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
mCamera = new Camera();
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

final float centerX = mCenterX;
final float centerY = mCenterY;
final Camera camera = mCamera;

final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

camera.save();

camera.rotateY(degrees);

camera.getMatrix(matrix);
camera.restore();

matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

}

}
```

I suggest you to refer the [Flip3dAnimation](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html) for this.